# Replay attacks and address differentiation after a hard fork?

Tags: hard-fork, attack

Just in case there will be some time a XMR Classic fork ...

Are there any technical solutions in the protocol to prevent replay-attacks after a hard fork?

Is there any possibility to distinguish whether a receiver’s address is on an old chain or the most current chain with the most hash rate and greatest block height?

What happens with a transaction is sent to non-valid address?

Comment: If by "non-valid address" you mean one that has an invalid checksum, you can't, it will be rejected. If you mean one where no wallet has been created yet, pretty sure the coins will just sit there until someone (by luck/chance) creates a wallet using that address.

Comment: @hyc thank you for the answer about the not valid adresses. It is clear for me now. How about the other two questions?

Answer (score 6):

1) The blockchain can fork at any time. From what I've observed, it only gets as far as 1-2 blocks down a branch before a chain reorganization occurs and the canonical longest branch is restored. Meanwhile, as noted here [Why does Monero prevent transactions from being spent without 10 confirmations?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/why-does-monero-prevent-transactions-from-being-spent-without-10-confirmations) it takes 10 blocks before any output is spendable. I believe this is the mechanism that you're asking for.

2) Wallet addresses are their own separate entity, they aren't dependent on a particular chain.

3) Non-valid addresses (with an invalid checksum) are rejected.

Comment: I think what is being asked is: if the people on the forked chain do not resolve by updating to the longest chain, and the people on the second chain treat their chain as a second currency, then a tx on a chain can also be relayed to the other chain. Like what happened with Ethereum. In that case, the mechanism above is inoperative.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. But in order to do an actual hard fork they'd have to change the version number in their txs, so they wouldn't actually be able to relay across chains.

Comment: Changing tx version is one possible way to prevent the issue from happening, yes. But if Monero forked like it forked last time (the main change was the 2 minute block time), then it was possible. Monero did not change tx version. Block version was changed, but both new blocks and old blocks could include a tx coming from any fork.